# XML Schema: elements with this name pattern have this attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this XML sample.

```
<root>
  <Ilhas_da_Madeira_e_Porto_Santo update-date="2016-04-01" update-time="14:14:46">
    <Santana update-author="sourceData" update-date="2016-04-01" update-time="14:14:48">
      <year1995 ncrimes="33"/>
      <year1994 ncrimes="58"/>
      <year1993 ncrimes="33"/>
    </Santana>
  </Ilhas_da_Madeira_e_Porto_Santo>
  <NE update-date="2016-04-01" update-time="14:14:48">
    <NE update-author="sourceData" update-date="2016-04-01" update-time="14:14:48">
      <year1995 ncrimes="163"/>
      <year1994 ncrimes="125"/>
      <year1993 ncrimes="126"/>
    </NE>
  </NE>
</root>
```

(XML Schema - xsd)
I am already grouping elements and attributes with `xs:group` and `xs:attributeGroup`.

Question:
Is it possible to do this: `elements with name_pattern="year(\d){4}" have attribute=ncrimes` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of XML Schema does not encourage an XML vocabulary design like this. It's generally considered bad form to have element or attribute names with an internal structure like this. Rather than

```
<year1995 ncrimes="163"/>
```

you should be using something like

```
<year y="1995" ncrimes="163"/>
```

With this design, you'll find that everything in the XML stack (not just XML Schema but things like XSLT, XPath, and DOM) works a little bit more smoothly.

But if you can't or won't change the vocabulary design, then your next best option is to define an element declaration for `name="year"` with `abstract="true"`, and then define elements `year1995`, `year1994` etc as elements in the substitution group of `year`.

Comment: Thank you. It was the conclusion I was getting at. I re designed my XML.